# Storing details from an input and displaying all the details with each new input. (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I have a problem with figuring out how to approach this code. I am trying to prompt the user for details of a person (such as name, age and telephone number) and then output all person information. Whenever another person's information is inputted, the information of the person before hand as well as the current one is outputted.

Should look like this:

My Input: Adam, 25, 12345678, France

Output: Adam, 25, 12345678, France

My Input Second time: Bob, 22, 12345678, Australia

Output second time:

```
               Adam, 25, 12345678, France             
               Bob, 22, 12345678, Australia
```

And so forth say 10 times which would create the table the tenth time with all details.
Any ideas on how I can do the whole create the table each time with more details? I've tried this to store variables but maybe looping an array is better? I'm new to Java as I've only picked it up recently. Any examples would be much appreciated. Thanks a heap!

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.useDelimiter(",");     

    String sName = scan.next();
    System.out.println(header);
    String sLast = scan.next();
    double sData1 = scan.nextDouble();
    double sData2 = scan.nextDouble();
    double sData3 = scan.nextDouble();
    int sData4 = scan.nextInt();
```

Will fully check back when I get back on my computer. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: can you paste the code which outputs it?

Comment: The '\n' is not read when you use nextDouble() or nextInt()....also if you put more code in here then the exact error can be pin point to..

Comment: You need a ArrayList to store the user information that has been input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the best ways to approach this is to possibly create a person class and just add each person into a list, printing the entire list after every entry. You'll find it easiest to creat a Person class and implement a toString() method for it:

```
public class TestCode {
    public static void main (String args []) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Person> peopleList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println("enter info: ");
            String name = input.next();
            String age = input.next();
            String phone = input.next();
            String location = input.next();
            peopleList.add(new Person(name, Integer.parseInt(age), Integer.parseInt(phone), location));

            for(Person p: peopleList)
                 System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
    }
}

class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    int phoneNumber;
    String location;

    Person(String n, int a, int p, String l){
        this.name = n;
        this.age = a;
        this.phoneNumber = p;
        this.location = l;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return(name + " " + age + " " + phoneNumber + " " + location);
    }
}
```

Something like this, although this example does not include removing the commas from your input. You should handle removing commas from the input before storing the values into the People class if you choose to take this route.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two scanners, one to separate the lines, and another to split by commas, then build the data you are scanning as a list of lists, and then iterate over it to print it out. something like this:

```
private static void processRecords() throws FileNotFoundException
{
  List<List<Object>> recordList = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
  // scan data line by line
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/tmp/foo.txt"));

  while(scanner.hasNextLine())
  {
     List<Object> record = new ArrayList<Object>();
     String line = scanner.nextLine();


     //remove all spaces, since nextDouble and nextInt
     //will choke on them:
     line = line.replaceAll(" ", "");

     //create a scanner just for this line
     Scanner recordScanner = new Scanner(line);
     recordScanner.useDelimiter(",");
     String sData1 = recordScanner.next();
     double sData2 = recordScanner.nextDouble();
     double sData3 = recordScanner.nextDouble();
     String sData4 = recordScanner.next();

     record.add(sData1);
     record.add(sData2);
     record.add(sData3);
     record.add(sData4);
     // add the record to the list.
     recordList.add(record);

     //print it out
     printHeader(recordList);

  }
}

private static void printHeader(List<List<Object>> recordList)
{
  //print it out
  for (List<Object> recordToPrint : recordList)
  {
     for (Object objToPrint : recordToPrint)
     {
        //print your records.
        System.out.print(objToPrint);
        System.out.print(",");
     }


     System.out.println();
  }
}
```

**Note:** I have changed the code to match your data - the code sample you supply doesn't quite match the data you gave.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scan.nextLine() to get each person's information, then use a List to store all the person information. At last, print all the person information that are stored in the List.

In this way, you can input one person's information at one time, such as, input **Adam, 25, 12345678, France** in console.

Below is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<String> personInformation = new ArrayList<String>();

    String line = null;

    while (!"exit".equals(line = scan.nextLine())) {
        personInformation.add(line);
        printPersonInformation(personInformation);
    }

}

private static void printPersonInformation(List<String> personInformation) {
    System.out
            .println("All the person information we have now is as follows:");
    for (String personInfo : personInformation) {
        System.out.println(personInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Create a class to hold the data about a person, with final fields, a suitable constructor and a `toString()` method:

```
public class Person {
    final String name, country;
    final int age, phone;
    public Person(String name, int age, int phone, String country) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + age + ", " + phone + ", " + country;
    }
    // getters omitted for brevity
}
```

Step 2: Create a List of these things:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Step 3: Scan in the 4 individual values then create a person them then add it to the list:

```
String name = scanner.next(); // etc for the other values
Person person = new Person(name, age, phone, country);
people.add(person);
```

When you are ready to print:

```
for (Person person : people) {
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

Comment: This is basically what my suggestion was. Why the final class variables?

Comment: No. Probably the biggest difference is that you are using a List<Object> to store a "person", which is a terrible design: It's completely untyped and difficult to use and debug. Any answer to any question that uses a List<List>> is a bad answer, unless in the most ex rational of cases (I can not recall such a case). Why final? Because it's good practice when the fields shouldn't change (in this context, these facts about a person are fixed)

Comment: Well I certainly don't recall pretending to be an expert in the subject. What I suggested works. I was merely asking about your use of final variables but if you'd rather be insulting than helpful feel free. Although any answer that insults rather than assist is also a terrible answer.

Comment: I just realize you have me mistaken for someone else. My list is not untyped and its identical to yours. Although the harsh answer still seems a bit nonconstructive.